Indicators and hazard working intermittently
I have a 2002 Renault Kangoo This week.
Right indicator started working intermittently and the next day the same with the left.
Then the hazard stopped working,but after I left the hazard on for a while it suddenly started working again but not regularly. When the hazard lights work then I can use the indicators any ideas?
All other lights working fine.
Thanks

If the problem were limited to the indicators but the hazard lights were working reliably, I would suggest that the switch in the base of the indicator stalk has gone intermittent. This is a known problem on this model as the electrical grease in the switch becomes aged and hardened. Cool weather makes the problem more apparent due to thickening grease.
But the problem is with both the indicators and hazard lights, and what they have in common is the indicator / hazard relay. So it's possible that the relay has gone bad.
This will be found in the fuse / relay box near the front passenger's knees:

The third relay from the left is for the indicators and flasher. It can be removed from its plug by pulling straight out. Installation of a new one is the reverse of removal.
Note that this is a suggestion, and without testing on a bench with a meter, power supply and load, there is no proof that the relay is bad. I don't have a pinout of the relay so I can't tell you how to test it.
You can ask a mechanic to estimate a price to diagnose and repair the problem, and then you can get a price for the relay alone from a parts supplier, and see if you want to take a chance on fixing it yourself for the much lower do-it-yourself price of a relay alone, knowing that replacing the relay might not fix the problem.
Image credit: Google Images
